# Wordpress Custom Blog Page

Tags: wordpress, blogs, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I want to customize the WordPress blog page like the one in the [photo](https://ibb.co/17pWQqx). I try to put the articles to have a different layout depending on their age, ie the last article to have the largest thumbnail, the next 2 to have the second-largest thumbnail, and the rest to have the smallest thumbnail.
This is the [site](https://www.thorne.com/take-5-daily) that inspired me.

Do you know if there is a way to achieve this?

*Am using elementor pro and crockblock for the rest website.*
*Theme: Hello*

Comment: I would say, using CSS Grid would be the most straight forward way, and would not require and additional PHP code. It is literally made for creating grids like these. Even automatically adding more rows is possible.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 0):

A pure CSS solution.

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid; 
  grid-auto-flow: row; 
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: auto auto; 
  gap: 32px; 
  justify-items: stretch; 
 }
  
  .item {
    /* All items */
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-column: span 2;
  }
  
  .item:nth-child(1) {
      /* First item */
      background-color: red;
  }
  
  .item:nth-child(2), .item:nth-child(3) {
      /* second and third */
      background-color: blue;
      grid-column: span 1;
  }
  
  .item:nth-child(n+4) {
    /* Every item after the 3rd */
    background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
</div>
```

As long as you don't need other random content in between, this is the most elegant and straight forward solution. The main reason i vouch for this, is that there is no complication of the existing theme code. And could basically just be added to the CSS Customizer in Wordpress.

Comment: Do you know any guide on how to make my own HTML page and put it on WordPress but be dynamic and all articles appear correctly on the blog page?

Comment: Do you have any knowledge with HTML, CSS, PHP and Wordpress in terms of coding? Of do you need an exact step by step guide?

Comment: This is my first real-life project. I have some experience with HTML, CSS, and PHP but I am trying to learn how can I use them on wordpress cms.

Comment: Very cool! I stared out similarly too. I am looking for someone to mentor. In case you would want that. 
--
I don't really have experience with elementor, and personally have the opinion that it doesn't help learning to develop websites. I could be wrong though.
I assume you could create a blog page via elementor somehow. Or you could go the usual wordpress way.

Comment: I am grateful thank you very much. If you know a website that has tutorials to get some ideas I would really appreciate it!

Comment: For wordpress in general it is really hard to point to a single source that is good. I have experienced that jamming a bunch of them together is the best way to go.

For pure HTML/CSS, Javascript and some PHP i recommend the basics on w3schools ( https://www.w3schools.com/css/ ). Follow trough the first chapter, then do some of the advanced ones that interests you, and next directly start or a real project. Try to do it as fast as you can - just try. Don't matter if it is full of mistakes and looks uggly. the most important thing is to write as much code as you can, and learn from it.

Comment: On a next step you can then either start a new project, or refactor what you did (clean up and make it better)